# Rest API 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, api, rest, yii2

I'm using the Yii2 Advanced Template and I added a new folder `api` to handle api requests and I'm getting `404 error` with `yii\base\InvalidRouteException`.

`api\config\main.php`

```
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'rest-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableSession' => false,
        ],
        'response' => [
            'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            'charset' => 'UTF-8',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            'class' => '\yii\web\Request',
            'enableCookieValidation' => false,
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v1/test']],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

and this is my `api\controllers\v1\TestController.php`

```
namespace api\controllers\v1;

use yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class TestController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\User';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => QueryParamAuth::className(),
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }

    public function actions() {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionTest()
    {
        return "1111";
    }
}
```

I think I'm doing something worng with namespacing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the v1 module. I also worked on the rest api

```
 <?php
    $params = array_merge(
       require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
       require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
       require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
       require(__DIR__ . '/aliases.php')
   );

      return [
'id' => 'app-api',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),    
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'controllerNamespace' => '@app\modules\v1\controllers',
'modules' => [
    'v1' => [
        'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
        'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
    ]
],
'components' => [        
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'request' => [
        'parsers' => [
            'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
        ]
    ],
    'response' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
    ],
    'urlManager' => [ 
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        //'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            //API V1
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/country'],  
                'tokens' => [
                    '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>',
                ],
            ],

        ],
    ],
],
'params' => $params,
  ];
```

For more information please find this [url](http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/)